# Castin with strtok warning

Tags: c, casting, compilation, warnings, strtok

I am writting this

```
int compare_dates(char* date1,char* date2,char* date3){
char* delim=malloc(sizeof(char) * 1);
delim ="-";
char *ptr = strtok(date1, delim);
}
```

and i get a warning ___ warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast
*ptr = strtok(date2, delim);

maybe somebody knows

Comment: Did you `#include` required headers?

Comment: this question is about code that is not posted!  Please post a [MCVE] so we can recreate the problem and help you debug it.

Answer (score 1):

There are several warnings and potential errors:

- `char *strtok(char *str, const char *delim)` is in `string.h`, you must include it to avoid the strtok's warning.
- Use `(void)variable;` `__attribute__((unused))` (GCC and CLang) or `[[maybe_unused]]` (C++17) to suppress the unused variable warnings.
- Assuming that `delim` on the heap is a valid design, use `free` to release the memory once the job is done (consider local variable instead).
- Bear in mind that you won't be able to pass a string literal to `strtok`.

Comment: Given `delim ="-";`, the memory to a single `char` allocated by `malloc()` is leaked.